# How to iterate multiple data from DAO

Tags: java, mysql

My code is like

```
for (Integer catId: catIds) {
        List<Object[]> objectList = invoiceDAO.periodWiseSalesRepoByRetailOrServices(ids, catId, startDate, endDate);
    }
```

By using the code above, I get data when `catId` = 0 from table like:

[image]

similarly when `catId` = 1, I got data like:

[image]

What I want is, if `date` and `shopid` is the same, I just want to calculate both sums. Sum means for date 20-12-2016 i get 6440 when catId=1 ,similarly in next image sum is 1809 for same shopId i want 8249 as total . like

[image]

What is the relevant approach?

Comment: Can you please update your first picture?

Comment: Thank you for reply image is updated now

Comment: What do you mean by 'both sums'? 
Also, please add the definition of the function `periodWiseSalesRepoByRetailOrServices` .

Comment: Done please have a look

Comment: you mean catid as stocktype.you filter it by stocktype and find rows.and also say that i want to sum when date and shopid column is equal even stocktype is 1 or 0.so you don't need to select rows by stocktype.because you don't pay attention to stocktype anywhere you only think about shopid and dates are equal.lets group by shopid and date then find net sum.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue as below:

```
if (map != null && map.containsKey(objects2[3].toString())) {
    map.put(objects2[3].toString(), map.get(objects2[3].toString()) + Double.parseDouble(objects2[2].toString()));
} else {
    map.put(objects2[3].toString(), Double.parseDouble(objects2[2].toString()));
}
```